# How to change a property of an element returned by a ForEach structure

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to do this:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    struct Element {
        var color: Color
    }

    @State var array = [Element, Element, Element]
```

```
ForEach(array){ element in
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(element.color)
        .tapAction {
            element.color = Color.red
        }
```

I can't do that because the element is a let constant.

How would I go about making the element a variable so that I can change its properties?

*Edited to add more code.

Comment: I think you're missing the concept of how ```ForEach``` works. You're not really suppose to update variables in there. Please share more code and explain a little more about what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Edited to add more code.

Comment: Ok, but what about the declaration of your variable. You do it in in your view? is it external? a global?

Comment: Edited to clarify further.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear what you want to do. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you should rewrite your code like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {

    struct Element {
        var color: Color
    }

    @State private var array = [Element(color: .red), Element(color: .green), Element(color: .blue)]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<array.count) { i in
            return Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(self.array[i].color)
                .tapAction {
                    self.array[i].color = Color.red
            }
        }
    }
}
```